# Unable to extract full text from .jpg image using pytesseract just partial text is extracted that to have spelling mistakes

Tags: python, ocr, text-extraction, python-tesseract

I am trying to extract data from a .jpg file using *pytesseract* but just partial text is extracted that to have spelling mistakes. Could anyone please help suggest how can I extract full text. I have attached .jpg for your reference code snippet which I am using for text extraction.

```py
img=Image.open('page-594-5.jpg')
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'
text=pytesseract.image_to_string(img,lang='eng')

print(text)
```

**Output I am getting:-**[image]

**Image from where data need to be extracted:-**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pytesseract has its own limitations even on printed text. Though to improve your performance, you can opt for some of the below solutions:

1) Each text character to be around 12pt in size (Font size).

2) Set your image resolution to around 300 DPI

[setting image resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174338/programmatically-change-image-resolution)

3) Denoise your image

[denoising image using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42065405/remove-noise-from-threshold-image-opencv-python)